# String formatting with "{0:d}".format gives Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'

Tags: python, string-formatting

If I understood the docs correctly, in python 2.6.5 string formatting "{0:d}" would do the same as "%d" with the String.format() way of formatting strings

```
" I have {0:d} dollars on me ".format(100.113)
```

Should print  "I have 100 dollars on me "

However  I get the error :

> ValueError: Unknown format code 'd'
>   for object of type 'float'

The other format operations do work.for eg.

```
>>> "{0:e}".format(112121.2111)
'1.121212e+05'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That error is signifying that you are passing a float to the format code expecting an integer.
Use `{0:f}` instead. Thus:

```
"I have {0:f} dollars on me".format(100.113)
```

will give:

```
'I have 100.113000 dollars on me'
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix ,but it does seem like this is a quirk. The %d would do the right thing and give me 100 for a float 100.111, but the :d does not.

Comment: Sorry Justin, I meant this to be a python centric quirk

Comment: `"%d" % 100.1` produces `100` for me with no error.  The new method of string formatting is different in this respect but I think I prefer that it won't implicitly convert data for you.  At least if you see `"{0:.0f}"` the enforced rounding is obvious.

Comment: @Hugh Simply by not reading closely :P, and my Java trained brain assuming String.format() meant Java which is obviously not the case.  I deleted the not useful comment.

Comment: @Dave Webb Agreed a 100% , enforced rounding is more elegant. I guess the perceived inconsistency vis a vis 0:d throwing a ValueError is acceptable

Comment: The docs do specify that d is an integer formatting code. http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Python 3 tries to move away from implicit truncation of floating point values, hence things like this change and `1/2` producing `0.5` instead of `0`

Comment: @DaveWebb `"{:.0f}"` is more reusable than `"{0:.0f}"` becuase saves you from the need to do `"{1:.0f}"`, `"{2:.0f}"`, etc. and lets automatic field numbering do that.

Comment: @DaveWebb no good for exact rounding though. `"{:.0f}"` rounds differently than `%d`, eg. `assert "{:.0f}".format(1.6) == "%d"%1.6` will raise.

Comment: Why would you ever use `"{0:d}".format(int(foo)` instead of just `"{0}".format(int(foo))` if it is forced now

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you understand correctly. However you are passing `float` (i.e. `100.113`), not `int`. Either convert it to `int`: `int(100.113)` or just pass `100`.

Comment: this works better than `"{:.0f}"`, because `int()` 'rounds' like `%d` and `.0f` does not. eg. `assert "{:.0f}".format(1.6) == "%d"%1.6` will raise, `"{:d}".format(int(1.6)) == "%d"%1.6` will not. But if you need to pass the formatstring beforehand eg. to a formatter and have no control over it's source than you cannot do the `int()`. (Well they'd either do `%` or `.format` anyway)

Answer (score 2):

*ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'* essentially means the interpreter is expecting an integer since you've provided **{0:d}** which is used as a placeholder to specify integer values but you've provided a float value instead to the format method.

And **one would expect python to do this implicit type conversion from float to int** since python doesn't have a problem converting an "int to a float" or a "float value to exponential form" as you stated but this is flagged as forced type conversions by the interpreter and won't work with format() method as of now.

So, the answer to your question is **Python’s .format() method requires that the value corresponding to the d format code be of integer type.**

Here are some of the alternates you could use instead:

- "I only have {:.0f} dollars on me ".format(100.113)
- "I only have %d dollars on me" % 100.113

Answer (score 1):

When using `format()`, or f-string (formatted strings) there are no automatic conversions from `float` to `int`. So assuming that the expected output was:

```
I have 100 dollars on me
```

The correct format spec to use would be `:.0f` meaning float with 0 decimal digits, which will round up/down the number for you:

```
"I have {0:.0f} dollars on me".format(100.113)
```

Some examples to show the rounding:

```
a = 13.1
b = 13.9
f'{a:.0f}' # 13
f'{b:.0f}' # 14
'{0:.0f}'.format(a) # 13
'{0:.0f}'.format(b) # 14
'{:.0f}'.format(a) # 13
'{:.0f}'.format(b) # 14
```

Answer (score -3):

delete 'd', since the object type might not be a number as in my case

Comment: Though Hong Ding is kind of wrong, considering that this is the only question on SO that is related to the error message `Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'XXX'`, it is worth mentioning that if you will use `{}` instead of `{d}` you won't have to guess what's wrong and will be able to see what is going on behind the scenes. (I suppose that is why he provided the "wrong" answer: because error message is kind of the same.)