# String formatting with “{0:d}” doesn't convert to integer

Tags: python, string-formatting

This is about the same issue as in [this question about floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627605/string-formatting-with-0d-format-gives-unknown-format-code-d-for-object-o).

When you've got a value that could get converted to an integer, the old `%d` would convert it, but format doesn't.

```
class MyIntegerTenClass:
    def __int__(self):
        return 10
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ten'
ten = MyIntegerTenClass()
print '%d, %02X, %s' % (ten, ten, ten) # ok
print  '{0}'.format(ten) # ok
print  '{0:d}, {0:02X}'.format(ten) # ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
```

Is there a way to modify the behaviour of format, without touching the class of the value to be formatted (without adding a `__format__` method to that class)?

Edit: My goal is to get the formatting dependent on the format string, but not on the value.
So if the format string says "d" or "x", convert the value to int and then to decimal or hexadecimal representation.
If the format string says "s", convert it to string directly. As the old `%` did.

Actually, I could even add a `__format__` method to the class of the value. But how do I check, in that method, if the given format specification is an integer format specification? Without reimplementing the format specification parser of the builtin format.

Edit: Here's a solution with `__format__` and exceptions. Any better ideas?

```
class MyIntegerTenClass:
    def __int__(self):
        return 10
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ten'
    def __format__(self, spec):
        fmt = '{0:%s}'%spec
        try:
            return fmt.format(str(self))
        except:
            return fmt.format(int(self))
ten = MyIntegerTenClass()
print '%d, %02X, %s' % (ten, ten, ten) # ok, prints "10, 0A, ten"
print  '{0:d}, {0:02X}, {0}'.format(ten) # ok, prints "10, 0A, ten"
```

Comment: It says ten is a string, you are trying to format it as a number.

Comment: I'd just use `!s` in the format specification, to force the conversion to a string before applying the field parameters: `'{0:d}, {0:02X}, {0!s}'.format(ten)`. Also, use `return format(int(self), spec)` no need to create a new string template here when there is a perfectly good `format()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first approach to this problem might be simply to `try` it:

```
class MyIntegerTenClass:
    def __int__(self):
        return 10
    def __str__(self):
        return 'ten'
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        try:
            s = format(str(self), format_spec)
        except ValueError:
            s = format(int(self), format_spec)
        return s
```

If `MyIntegerTenClass` *can* be inserted into the format string as a string, it will be. If not, it will be converted into an int and resubmitted to `format`.

```
>>> print '{0}, {0:s}, {0:d}, {0:02X}, {0:f}'.format(ten)
ten, ten, 10, 0A, 10.000000
```

If you want the default representation to be `10` instead of `ten`, you need only swap the conversion lines:

```
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        try:
            s = format(int(self), format_spec)
        except ValueError:
            s = format(str(self), format_spec)
        return s
```

Test output:

```
>>> print '{0}, {0:s}, {0:d}, {0:02X}, {0:f}'.format(ten)
10, ten, 10, 0A, 10.000000
```

As an addendum, I don't believe you'll be able to get the behavior you want without defining `__format__`; however, you can develop a more sophisticated approach using a [`Formatter`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) object. Still, I think the exception-based approach gives you a lot of built-in functionality for free.

Comment: Thanks. Seems we got the same solution at about the same time (see my second edit). Though your solution seems a bit nicer since it doesn't need that '{0:%s}'%spec. I didn't realize there's a format function you can call like this.

Answer (score 1):

pass an integer instead of a string and it'll work fine.

```
>>> print  '{0:d}'.format(1)
1
>>> print  '{0:d}'.format('1')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    print  '{0:d}'.format('1')
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: I knew that. But I don't want to pass an integer. I want to pass an object of my class which can be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It says ten is a string, you are trying to format it as a number.

Try wrapping it in a cast:

```
>>> print  '{0:d}, {0:02X}'.format(int(ten))
10, 0A
```

Comment: Doesn't work for my use-case. I don't want to change the value given to format.